# What is the difference between api.mybluemix vs api.ng.bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

What is the difference between the two?
I am using `cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net`.
Another tutorial on the IBM website uses `cf api https://api.mybluemix.net`. 
Which doesn't seem to be working. Is it outdated and not working or am I using it wrong? On the Bluemix website they only show two CF API endpoints.

1. api.ng.bluemix.net
2. api.eu-gb.bluemix.net

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#overview/overview.html

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the [api.ng.bluemix.net](https://api.ng.bluemix.net) or [api.eu-gb.bluemix.net](https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net) as these are to two addresses for the two regions that are currently available in Bluemix. When new regions are created then you would use the api endpoint for that new region to log into it.

So if you have apps and services in the eu-gb (UK) region then you would log into [api.eu-gb.bluemix.net](https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net). If you are using us-south region then you would log into [api.ng.bluemix.net](https://api.ng.bluemix.net)

The difference between a `mybluemix.net` address and a `bluemix.net` address is that the `bluemix.net` address is reserved for official IBM Bluemix provided applications such as [console.ng.bluemix.net](https://console.ng.bluemix.net), [api.ng.bluemix.net](https://api.ng.bluemix.net) or [status.ng.bluemix.net](https://status.ng.bluemix.net). The `mybluemix.net` addresses are the user applications that are running on Bluemix, these might or might not be developed by IBM.

Comment: It seems weird that they would use "cf api https://api.mybluemix.net" when it doesn't work. Another tutorial which was not on the IBM website uses "cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net" which seems to work. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes it seems like a bug in the docs, do you have a link to that particular page that states to use 'api.mybluemix.net'?

Comment: sure, It's under the 8 step "c.connect to bluemix and deploy the application"  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-deployrest-app/index.html

Comment: I have been trying to create an api for quite a while now but I have been running into a lot of road blocks. like creating a database on bluemix or even accessing the actual rest endpoints. Can you tell me how I can access the api? In the tutorial it mentions calling the api via "/v1/products". What is the whole uri? Is it <my app name>.ng.bluemix.net/v1/products? Sorry for the long question. Should I create another thread?

Comment: apparently you can only comment once every 90 minutes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097803/how-to-access-rest-api-endpoints-for-bluemix

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you getting the SSL Cert error.

Will you please try and see if cf login works for you by giving it the endpoint directly ? http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/whats-new-v6.html

```
Example => 
    >>cf login -a api.ng.bluemix.net -u xxx@yy.zz -o xxx@yy.zz -s dev
    API endpoint: api.ng.bluemix.net
    Password>
    Authenticating...
    OK

    Targeted org xxx@yy.zz
    Targeted space dev

    API endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.14.0)
    User:           xxx@yy.zz
    Org:            xxx@yy.zz
    Space:          dev
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. api.ng.bluemix.net works but I read an article on the IBM Bluemix website. Which should be the official go to source and it told me to use cf api api.mybluemix.net. Which does not work. Thanks for taking the time to help though :)