# How to access REST api endpoints for Bluemix

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud

I followed an IBM Blumix article on "Build and deploy a REST API on IBM Bluemix with PHP and MySQL".
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-deployrest-app/index.html

However it never says how to access the actual endpoints(I think I am using the right word). It says to call "/v1/products" to list all products. I am very new to bluemix and not too sure exactly what to append "/v1/products" to. Should I append it to make ">projectName<.mybluemix.net/v1/products"? This is not working. I get the error message

"Not Found

The requested URL /v1/products was not found on this server."

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have followed the developerWorks article then you should just be able to access the endpoint by doing a GET call (i.e. just adding this to a web browser) this url:

`your_app_route.mybluemix.net\v1\products`

or if you deployed to the UK (eu-gb) region then the url is:

`your_app_route.eu-gb.mybluemix.net\v1\products`

then append either .xml or .json to that url for the desired response type. The endpoint is defined in your app code, and from reading the developerWorks article it is set in the PHP code at this point:

```
 $app->path('v1', function($request) use ($app) {

    $app->path('products', function($request) use ($app) { 


    // GET /v1/products[.xml|.json]
    // list all products
    $app->get(function() use ($app)  {

      $products = Product::all();         

      // handle requests for XML content
      $app->format('xml', function($request) use($app, $products) {
        return $app->response(200, convert_array_to_xml($products->toArray()))
                      ->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
      });

      // handle requests for JSON content
      $app->format('json', function($request) use($app, $products) {
        return $products->toArray();
      });
```

The `your_app_route` is the route/hostname name you can define when you do the `cf push` command, if you don't explicitly set this route (`-n` option or `--random-route` option) then it will be set to the name of your Bluemix application. You can see what the url is by looking at the Bluemix UI console for your app (should be at the top of the page) or by looking at the end of the `cf push` command where is says `urls:`

From the error you are getting it sounds like the app is starting, but the web server is not directing the requests to the Bullet module. You might want to check that Step 8(b) has been done correctly.

Comment: I went back and completed step 8(b) I had previously skipped it because I thought it was talking about a local test environment. After I completed 8(b) and tried accessing the uri http://products-api-111.mybluemix.net/v1/products I get nothing in return, just a blank page. The tutorial uses mySQL. However I am using SQL database which uses DB2. I had to change the queries to create and insert data. I have a table called PRODUCTS with a couple rows of data, so I am not sure if that would be the problem.

Comment: when you said append .json to the url did you mean something like http://products-api-111.mybluemix.net/v1/products.json     ?

Comment: yes http://products-api-111.mybluemix.net/v1/products.json is what i mean. This should return the data in a json format that you would be able to see in a web browser. You might want to look at the logs of your app to see why it isn't returning anything, and add more logging if needed. `cf logs yourappname --recent` is the command to use to view the recent stream log information.

Comment: Not too sure what it means, I think maybe I made a mistake with the database. I am using the SQL Database instead of the mySQL. The table name of my database got automatically capitalized when I think the original should be lowercase. So mine is "PRODUCTS" and in the original mySQL it is just "products".

Comment: Here is the error code:       FAILED
Error dialing traffic controller server: Get https://doppler.ng.bluemix.net:443/apps/aa596165-e99b-4e03-9536-375fa785be01/recentlogs: dial tcp 75.126.70.44:443: ConnectEx tcp: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
Please ask your Cloud Foundry Operator to check the platform configuration (traffic controller endpoint is wss://doppler.ng.bluemix.net:443).

Comment: How can I clone or download this repository. There is no link or download button. https://hub.jazz.net/project/vvaswani/products-api/overview#

Comment: The 'doppler' error is related to the logging service rather than your own, you can safely ignore these (although it potentially means you might be missing log information). The repo you linked to is a based on SCM rather than git so you will need to click on the 'configure eclipse client' to be able to get the code into eclipse using the RTC plugin. The other option is to choose the 'edit code' option, fork the code and then use the browser IDE to change code.

Comment: I forked it and managed to download it by going to File->Export in the online browser. It has gotten late so I will try again in the morning. If it still does not work I will be inclined to think the problem is my database. Do you have any resources on creating a rest api on bluemix? And thanks so much for all your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: "online browser" *face palm. *Browser IDE